# Не выводятся параметры в конструкторе

Tags: java, intellij-idea, конструктор, параметры

Возникла такая проблема: не получается вызвать конструктор и передать параметры в `new Employee()`.

В видео уроке IDEA создает поля в скобках: `name:`, `position:`, `salary:`, чтобы можно было подставить туда свои значения:

```java
Employee(name: "", position: "", salary: 0);
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы в скобках при вводе определялось `name`, `position`, `salary`? Оно подставляет автоматом или это какая-то комбинация клавиш? И если я ввожу параметры в скобки — ошибка исчезает, но параметры все равно не выводятся на экран.

Подскажите, в чем проблема, заранее спасибо)

[image: Где ошибка]

[image: Конструктор 1 часть]

[image: Конструктор 2 часть]

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Параметры в кострукторе указываются ровно в том порядке, в котором они объявляются при создании этого самого конструктора. 
также посмотрите про перегрузку конструктора

Comment: Это подсказки самой среды разработки, к коду они отношения не имеют. В Intellij Idea есть много способов облегчить разработку, конкретно [это называется Inlay Hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#inlay-hints) и надо смотреть в настройках. Обычно они появляются уже после введения параметров в качестве сопроводительной информации для дополнительного контроля, но не всегда. Так же по ссылке можете посмотреть другие полезные возможности.

Comment: `если я ввожу параметры в скобки — ошибка исчезает, но параметры все равно не выводятся на экран.` Зачем вы делаете @override для метода `toString()` ? Чтобы вывести на экран модель, содержащуюся в конструкторе, вам нужно написать метод "print" и где нибудь его вызвать.

Answer (score 0):

Такой конструкции в языке Java не существует:

```java
new Employee(name: "", position: "", salary: 0); // не скомпилируется
```

То, что вы видите перед аргументами — это такая приколюшка среды разработки IDEA. Как вам уже подсказал @AlexKrass, это [Inlay Hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#inlay-hints).

Чтобы в Java вызвать конструктор, просто перечислите аргументы через запятую:

```java
new Employee("", "", 0);
```